# Cual es el problema que tiene esta consulta?

Tags: mysql, nodejs, rest

Buenas, tengo esta consulta que hago con mi **API REST** en **NodeJS**

```
router.get("/create/:id/:name/:img",function(req,res){
    var query = "INSERT INTO ??, (??, ??, ??) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
    var table = ["demos", "id", "name", "img", req.params.id, req.params.name, req.params.img];
    query = mysql.format(query,table);
    connection.query(query,function(err,rows){
        if(err) {
            res.json(err);
        } else {
            res.json(rows);
        }
    });
});
```

Y el problema es que me devuelve este error

```
{"code":"ER_PARSE_ERROR","errno":1064,"sqlState":"42000","index":0}
```

Yo no le encuentro el problema, pero... seguro alguno tiene solución jeje, saludos.

Comment: Verificaste que la coma que tienes en después del INSERT INTO ??, no esta de más? "INSERT INTO ??  (??, ??, ??) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con @OJVM verifica esa coma creo que esta demas

Comment: Yo también apoyo a **OJVM**, no estás poniendo la tabla en la cual quieres insertar ni tampoco los valores de los campos.

Comment: Yo de ti evaluaría algún ORM (que son ligeritos en Node.js). Con sequelize todo es más sencillo y es basado en promesas que, si combinas con Node.js 7 y async/await, obtienes un código muy limpio y ordenado.

Answer (score -1):

Verifica la coma tu consulta debe ser la siguiente.

```
"INSERT INTO ?? (??, ??, ??) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
```

Comment: Jajaj es verdad, tenia una coma innecesaria, pero ahora tengo este error ER_DUP_ENTRY